# Undefined citations when use latex-workshop in VS-code, while it works well in texstudio

Tags: bibtex, xetex, zotero, better-bibtex

Thanks for your attention, English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

I used to write my paper in latex with texstudio and I export my bibliographies by Zotero with add-in "better BibTeX". It works well since bib file can auto-update and citations keys can be compiled in the texstudio (by xelatex).

However, when I use VSCode as my tex-editor with "latex-workshop", it seems that there's something wrong:

```
"message": "Citation `zhouDecelerationChinaHuman2020' on page 1 undefined.\n",
```

I have checked the bib file and the cite key, everything is right. When I compile my tex-file, it still worked well in texstudio. Surprisingly, once it has been compiled once in Texstudio, these citations also work properly in VSCode! But when I insert new citations, similar error occurred again.

I have set VSCode following [the documentation for latex-workshop](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Intellisense) but it doesn't work:

```
"latex-workshop.kpsewhich.enabled": true,
"latex-workshop.intellisense.package.enabled":true,
```

And I have set xelatex in recipes (same as texstudio):

```
  "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
{
  "name": "xelatex",
  "tools": [
    "xelatex"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "latexmk",
  "tools": [
    "latexmk"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex*2",
  "tools": [
    "pdflatex",
    "bibtex",
    "pdflatex",
    "pdflatex"
  ]
}
],
```

I've been bothered by this question for a long time and would appreciate any help someone might be able to provide!

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I discovered a solution that may help you.
In the Tex section of the Latex-Workshop extension (in the most left vertical panel) it should appear the 'commands' section. Inside that section, it should appear de option 'Build Latex Projects' -> 'Recipe: pdflatex-bibtex-pdflatex x2'. If you click on that it should rebuild the bibtex database using the last .bib file, and that should solve your problem.
The problem occurs because the default pdflatex building motor in VS it not automatically update de .bib file to its bibtex database; and with that problem although it can recognizes the cites in the IDE, it cannot put them in the built document.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, this solution is inconvenient but it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That recipe delte .bbl and throw error. Manual pdflatex + bibtex + pdflatex2x works. Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

After following all the procedures, the problem still remains unsolved. Then I realize that I didn't 'make clean' before I compile the tex file again. So I applied two other possible reasons for the dysfunction:

1. bib file contains illegal characters (For example if someone download a bibtex straightly from some website, it may contain illegal character such as greek letters or others. This may cause a failure in importing the corresponding bib file, what's worse, we can not even import other bib files which are totally correct.)
2. After replace all the illegal characters, one need to 'make clean' before compile again.

Comment: 3. Check if there is a repetition between different bib files. If one download a template Tex file and there exists a bunch of bib files, and if he/she wants to add his/her own bib file, one should make sure that the added bib file should not contain same entry

Comment: If I understand it correctly, it's an assumption? If so, it would not be an answer in the sense of 1 solution to 1 problem (initial question). However, may be if reprhrased or added by a simple proof this may be all that's needed to turn it into a solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/232608)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use `xelatex->bibtex->xelatex->xelatex` with `MikTex`

1. Use terminal or texworks to check whether the command works.

> Reason: In the settings.json of vscode, only the command is specified(e.g. "xelatex"). However, there may exist various engines/executives in the computer accroding to that.
>
> So, using **terminal command** to check if it works well w/o LaTex Workshop.

e.g.

```
xelatex test.tex
```

2. **Check the Log!**

*Actually I always find it hard to read the log in VSCode. So try using **terminal command to check the output in terminal***

it reminds me to **update** miktex.

After updating that(open MikTex Console), it works as is expected!