# References undefined while autocomplete does find the reference

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, auto-completion, undefined, vscode

When I add references to my file it outputs a question mark and the error message "citation 'label' in page '1' undefined." However, autocomplete does notice the reference which implies to me the path to the reference and the reference itself are correct. Am I missing something obvious?
I added a minimal working example of my latex code below, which I edited in VSCode.
Any suggesting are appreciated, thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}
Whenever i cite a citation \cite{KOEL1} it shows up in autocomplete.
However, the cite command is still outputting errors and question marks.

the error is :

LaTeX Warning: Citation `KJRATPROB' on page 1 undefined on input line 52.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{reference}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit solution:
This was a bibtex problem which was solved by running biber "document name" in the terminal.
It also helped to change my imports to:
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Sorry as José says, no code no help. See it from our side, we have no idea what you are doing so how can we help. You mention autocomplete, but never even mention which editor you are using.

Comment: This sounds like expected behaviour if `bibtex` hasn't been run, information about the citation isn't available to `*latex` compilations as `*latex` extracts references from an intermediate `.bbl` file generated by `bibtex`  (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852). It does seems to have come up before with VS Code https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553023, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/666883.

Comment: ok, with the edit it sounds very much like `bibtex` is not being run if the output pdf file contains `[?]` instead of the citations.

Comment: Thanks I needed to run biber documentname in the terminal.
I also changed my packes to:
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}

Comment: @dorusBoogaard switching to use `biber`/`biblatex` isn't necessary over `bibtex`/`\bibliographystyle`/`\bibliography`, but it'll certainly do the job.